# dropping the 3rd element of a list

Tags: haskell

```
dropEvery':: (Eq(a), Show(a)) => [a] -> Int -> [a]
dropEvery' list n = concatTuple $ span (== list!!(n-1)) list
    where concatTuple (x1, x2) = (take (length(x1)-2) x1) ++ x2
```

I've come with this code to remove an element of a list, so

```
main :: IO ()
main = print $ dropEvery' "abcdefghik" 3
```

should print `abdefghik`

I think that the problem is in `list!!(n-1)`, it does not return the correct element. What is wrong? I don't know yet how to print the result of it to debug.

Comment: If you're just trying to drop the third element, you could consider `dropThird list = take 2 list ++ drop 3 list` (of course, this naturally extends to dropping the nth element).

Comment: So you want to drop all `c`s in the list? It looks like the name hints that you want to drop *every* third element, that your code suggests that you want to remove all items equal to the one at index `2`; and that your test example suggests you only remove the one with index `2`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@DDub has shared a solution to the problem already, so I will address the issue in your attempt. The problem lies with how you are using `span`.

`span` returns empty list as the first element of the result with your condition. Internally, `span` is calling `takeWhile` on the list with your condition for the first element of its output. `takeWhile` checks if the first element of the list satisfies the predicate passed in, and since that is not the case, it stops further processing and returns an empty list. As a result, you end up calling your `concatTuple` function with an empty list as the first parameter, which is why the overall function doesn't behave the way you expect it to.